# Spring WebFlux: set max file(s) size for uploading files

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, upload, spring-webflux

I'm using flux of FileParts to upload files `@RequestPart(FILES) Flux<FilePart> files`

And trying to limit maximum size of files. Looks like old way does not work:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=1MB
```

And I dont have any methods to get file size in `FilePart` interface. So is ther any way to limit max size of uploaded file in webflux, whithout copying it? I know that there are headers like `Content-Length`, but it does not look secure way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Web on Reactive Stack documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) states the following:

> For file parts written to disk, there is an additional maxDiskUsagePerPart property to limit the amount of disk space per part. There is also a maxParts property to limit the overall number of parts in a multipart request. To configure all 3 in WebFlux, you’ll need to supply a pre-configured instance of MultipartHttpMessageReader to ServerCodecConfigurer.

I was able to apply it via this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader partReader = new SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader();
        partReader.setMaxParts(1);
        partReader.setMaxDiskUsagePerPart(10L * 1024L);
        partReader.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);

        MultipartHttpMessageReader multipartReader = new MultipartHttpMessageReader(partReader);
        multipartReader.setEnableLoggingRequestDetails(true);

        configurer.defaultCodecs().multipartReader(multipartReader);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the setMaxParts() limit unfortunately also applies to form fields, not just files.

Comment: Also note that the shown configuration uses the **Synchronoss** part reader instead of the `DefaultPartHttpMessageReader`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.html

Comment: How can set the MaxParts for individual endpoints. Say I have and API that should only take up to 3 files to upload and another API to take 2 requestParts as string and up to 5 files to upload? if you do  setMaxParts(3) then the second API does not allow more than 1 file to be uploaded. any Idea how to apply the limit per endpoint and not as a general rule?