# Spring Webflux - limit of file upload size (spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size does not work)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Is there a file upload size for `FilePart`? This is not working: I set it to be 100B but I can upload a file of 8KB.

```yml
spring:
  servlet.multipart: # see MultipartProperties
    max-file-size: 100B
    max-request-size: 200B
```

I understand this is for multipart, but I am using FilePart:

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/{id}/draft/target", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public Mono<TargetsValidationResponse> uploadTargets(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id, @RequestPart(name = "file") Mono<FilePart> file) {
        return file.flatMap(parser::parseTargets)
                .zipWith(promotionServiceAdapter.getDraft(id))
                ...;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424649/spring-webflux-set-max-files-size-for-uploading-files

Comment: Yes, just found it in SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader. That's the way. But I also find `spring.codec.max-in-memory-size` in the doc, saying that `Limit on the number of bytes that can be buffered whenever the input stream needs to be aggregated. This applies only to the auto-configured WebFlux server and WebClient instances. By default this is not set, in which case individual codec defaults apply. Most codecs are limited to 256K by default.` I don't know what it is.

Comment: Make it an answer or mark it as duplicate. If you can!